# Riddle - Name the Bee

Tags: riddle, english, computer-science

> What is the name of the Bee, Which flew all over the United States in its lifetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the name of the Honey-Bee, Which flew all over the United States in its lifetime?

> [BuzzBee](https://popicon.life/throwback-buzzbee-honey-nut-cheerios/)

Comment: Nice ..one ...but not correct..

Answer (score 3):

The Bee that flew all over the United States in its lifetime could be:

> [Betsy Ross Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betsy_Ross_flag)

> [image: Betsy Ross Flag Image]

Comment: How is it a bee?

Comment: @msh210, it starts with a B.  It was the first thing I thought of.  Based on the new tag, I doubt it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the name of the Honey-Bee, Which flew all over the United States in its lifetime?

> [Barry B. Benson](https://en.wikipedia.org/?oldid=1091377262#Plot)

Comment: not correct..  :(

Answer (score -4):

> Its **USB** (Universal Serial Bus)

> United states = US,

> Bee           = B

Comment: How does this explain "flew". I think the flag answer fits better than this.